# Why isn't Facebook Ads Manager able to use my Instagram videos to create a custom audience?

Tags: facebook, instagram, ads

I have a business Instagram account linked to an Ad Account in Facebook Ads Manager. While I can successfully use the videos posted with this Instagram account to create ads, I cannot use them to create an engagement custom audience.

If I follow the steps described in the Facebook Help Center (https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1099865760056389?id=2469097953376494), I get stuck on step 7:

> **Instagram business profile**: Select an Instagram business profile and tick the boxes next to the video(s) that you want to use. You can choose multiple videos from multiple business profiles for one audience.

After I select the business profile, no videos appear where they should. Instead, I just get an error message saying there are no videos posted on the selected Instagram profile. This doesn't make much sense to me because I can create ads based on the videos posted on this account, so Ads Manager should be able to find them.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else faces a similar issue, my problem was that the account I was working with was actually a Creator account and not a Business account. Changing it to a Business account solved the problem.